# Stable convergence equivalence

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that a sequence of random variables $X_n\to X$ $\mathcal{G}$-stabily. Does it mean that the conditional cdfs of $X_n$ given $\mathcal{G}$ converge a.s. to those of $X$?

---

It seems that the answer is positive. Stable convergence is equivalent to 
$$
\mathsf{E}[\exp\{itX_n\};G]\to\mathsf{E}[\exp\{itX\};G]
$$
for every $G\in\mathcal{G}$ and $t\in \mathbb{R}$ (e.g. Corollary 3.19 in Häusler, *[Stable Convergence and Stable Limit Theorems](https://books.google.ca/books?id=0sfWCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&dq=Corollary%203.19&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjtl8Lk0uHbAhVHw1QKHW_jAFsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=Corollary%203.19&f=false)*). So by the dominated convergence theorem
$$
\mathsf{E}[\exp\{itX\};G]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[\exp\{itX_n\};G]=\mathsf{E}[\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[\exp\{itX_n\}\mid \mathcal{G}];G]
$$
which means that $\mathsf{E}[\exp\{itX\}\mid\mathcal{G}]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{E}[\exp\{itX_n\}\mid \mathcal{G}]$ a.s. and the latter implies that the conditional cdfs converge a.s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. In fact, stable convergence is weaker than the a.s. convergence of conditional distributions (see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.0469.pdf)). The flaw in the argument is that $\lim_n\mathsf{E}[\exp(itX_n)\mid \mathcal{G}_n]$ may not exist.